# How to deal with recursing through a list in Haskell (transpose operation)

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, transpose, non-exhaustive-patterns

While I understand that there may be transpose or ZipList functions in Haskell, I am trying to build my own transpose function that will take *n* lists of equal length *m* and transpose them into *m* lists of length *n*.

So far I have the function nearly working with the following code:

```
list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

head' (x:xs) = x

head'' [] = []
head'' (xs:lxs) = head' xs:head'' lxs

tail' [] = []
tail' (x:xs) = xs

tail'' [] = []
tail'' (xs:lxs) = tail' xs:tail'' lxs

merge (xs:lxs) = (head' xs:head'' lxs):(merge (tail' xs:tail'' lxs))
```

and I get the following output when I run > `merge list` in ghci I get:

```
[[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9],[*** Exception: list2.hs:16:1-16: Non-exhaustive patterns in function head'
```

which I am pretty sure means that the base case of the empty list on my `head'` function is missing. The list is transposed, just not closed. How do I deal with that problem in this case? I have an inkling that it might have to do with `Maybe`, but I'm having trouble implementing it that way.

Comment: `head' (x:xs) = x`, but what is `head' []`?

Comment: Since `head' xs:head'' lxs = head'' (xs:lxs)`, you can collapse `merge (xs:lxs) = (head' xs:head'' lxs):...` to `merge (xs:lxs) = (head'' (xs:lxs)):...`. Similar equational reasoning applies to the `...`, giving `merge (xs:lxs) = (head'' (xs:lxs)):(tail'' (xs:lxs))`. At that point there's not much point to pattern matching; `merge lxs = head'' lxs:tail'' lxs`. But now you should definitely be suspicious: this definition of `merge` obviously always calls `(:)` and never `[]`. So how does one get to the "end" of the `merge`'s output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add exit conditions:

```
merge [] = []
merge ([]:xss) = merge xss
```

Comment: So when does `merge ([]:xss) = merge xss` run as opposed to the other two definitions of `merge`?

Answer (score 0):

`map` is all you need, in addition to the existing `head` and `tail` functions. For simplicity, this assumes that the input is always a non-empty list (i.e., `xs` might be `[[],[],[]]`, but never `[]` alone, so there's no problem with using `head` or `tail`.)

```
> map head list
[1,4,7]
> map tail list
[[2,3],[5,6],[8,9]]
> let foo xs = if null (head xs) then [] else map head xs : foo (map tail xs)
> foo list
[[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]]
```